# EOF Error when importing python package

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror, eoferror

I am working on a project which utilizes the wbdata package for python, which is a wrapper for the world bank api.  It was working fine until I made what I have guessed to be to large of a request of data, which I had to cancel, and now the package won't even load when I use the import wbdata function.  Here's what I get

```
Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:40:02) [MSC 

v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.

In [1]: import wbdata as wb

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-ae1872a5f07c>", line 1, in <module>
    import wbdata as wb

  File "C:\Users\Josh New\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\wbdata\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .api import (get_country, get_data, get_dataframe, get_panel,

  File "C:\Users\Josh New\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\wbdata\api.py", line 31, in <module>
    from . import fetcher

  File "C:\Users\Josh New\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\wbdata\fetcher.py", line 104, in <module>
    if not len(CACHE.cache)== 0:

  File "C:\Users\Josh New\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\wbdata\fetcher.py", line 82, in cache
    cache = pickle.load(cachefile)

EOFError


In [2]:
```

Could someone please help me out with getting this package working again?

Thanks

Josh

EDIT- Ok after running the %debug cachefile.name I get the following;

```
   %debug cachefile.name
NOTE: Enter 'c' at the ipdb>  prompt to continue execution.
> c:\users\josh new\anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py(15)decode()
     14     def decode(self,input,errors='strict'):
---> 15         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
     16 


ipdb> c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Josh New\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py", line 817, in _run_with_debugger
    deb.run(code, code_ns)
  File "C:\Users\Josh New\Anaconda\lib\bdb.py", line 400, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cachefile' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ipython's magic `%debug` and check what `cachefile`'s file name is. If it's a regular file, name should be accessible as `cachefile.name`.

Then nuke that file.

Comment: %debug
> c:\users\josh new\anaconda\lib\site-packages\wbdata\fetcher.py(84)cache()
     83             except IOError:
---> 84                 cache = {}
     85             self.__cache = cache

Comment: Oh good point, `cachefile` is a file object, you need to find file name, thus `cachefile.name` if it was created with `open()/file()` or otherwise you need to read the source code.

Comment: I am assuming by nuke you mean delete?

Comment: yes indeed; btw, looking through source at github, file name is also accessible as `self.path`

Comment: i deleted the bdb.py file but that doesnt seem to have worked

Answer (score 0):

I think I have fixed it by going the wbdata folder in Appdata\Local\wbdata and deleting the cache file that was in it.  seems to work now.